# Travelling within Schengen with passport that doesn't have visa

Tags: schengen, denial-of-entry, austria

I have lost my Kazakh passport in Germany together with my residence permit. The issue is that I need to travel to Vienna for some business issues in the next 10 days. Due to having a double citizenship - I also have a Russian passport, which has no visa or residence permit in it.

Am I allowed to travel within the Schengen countries with a valid passport that doesn't have visa in it?

Answer (score 2):

the short answer is no.

according to this:

https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/who-needs-schengen-visa/

both Russians and Kazakhstan citizens need a valid visa to enter Austria.

Since you lost the BlueCard, you can not prove that you are allowed to move in the Schengen area...

Answer (score 2):

Germany now issues card-sized eAT residency permits which are not in your passport. The old passport stickers remain valid for some years, but sticker holders can get the card in "exceptional cases" and also if they would need a new sticker e.g. for a new passport. So you will get an eAT sooner or later.

Ask how quick you can get one. At a guess, 10 days will not be enough, but I have no idea if there is expedited processing.